# "General" Solutions to sin(x) = cos(x)

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the general solution to sin(${\alpha}$)=cos(${\alpha}$). The question did not mention in which quadrant ${\alpha}$ was in. Below is my solution:

$\sin({\alpha})=\cos({\alpha})$

$\sin({\alpha})=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - {\alpha}\right)$

-- Since the general solution for $sin({\alpha}) = sin({\beta})$ is ${\alpha} = \pi n + {(-1)^n}({\beta})$ --

**${\alpha} = \pi n + {(-1)^n}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - {\alpha}\right)$ This the answer I got.**

However, the book did it a different way. Instead of converting cos to sin as I did, the book converted sin to cos, which gave a completely different answer. Here is what the book did:

$\sin({\alpha})=\cos({\alpha})$

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - {\alpha})=\cos({\alpha})$

-- Since the general solution for cos(${\alpha}$) = cos(${\beta}$) is ${\alpha} = 2\pi n \pm {\beta}$ --

**${\alpha} = 2\pi n \pm \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - {\alpha}\right)$ This the answer the book got.**

From this, I am unsure weather to convert sin to cos (like the book did) or cos to sin (like I did), since they both seem like valid steps. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---Edited---
Thank you for your answers! I have modified the question. Could you please look at the picture and help?

[image]

Comment: Note that your answers only exist when $n$ is even, not odd, and the book's answers only exist when you take the plus sign, not the minus sign. So, in both cases, you get $\alpha=2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$.

Comment: Neither of the two "answers" is quite satisfactory.  Instead you should get an expression for solutions $\alpha$ that make $\sin(\alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$.  Presumably you know the two solutions in period $[0,2\pi]$ and adding multiples of $2\pi$ preserves the equality of sine and cosine values.  So compare what you've written to the two "known" solutions in the base interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: That is not how to use MathJax. Put the first `$` before you write the first symbol of the equation, then write the entire equation until it is complete, then put the second `$` for that equation. There should never be any `$` inside an equation unless you actually need to show "dollars" with `\$`. If you do this correctly, your equations (which right now are practically illegible -- I honestly couldn't tell when you were writing $-$ rather than $\cdot$ in a couple of places) will be much better formatted. Also, use `\sin` and `\cos`.

Comment: Please, don't  mix MathJax with text. Instead of writing`sin($\frac{}{2}$ - ${\alpha}$)`, write `$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - {\alpha})$`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have added a screenshot for the original problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Ordinarily we discourage screenshots for things that are just equations and text. But the screenshot at least clarifies the question, and now we can see that the "answers" show in the earlier part of the question are only used as intermediate calculations and not the final answer. That is good.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually easier to divide by $\cos\alpha$, such that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
   \sin\alpha &=& \cos\alpha \\
   \tan\alpha &=& 1 \\
       \alpha &=& \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi k, \;k\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{array}
$$
since the tangent is a $\pi$-periodic function with $\arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Converting in $\sin$ we obtain

$$\sin\left(\frac32 x\right)=\sin\left(\frac\pi 2 -\frac32 x\right)$$

and therefore

$$\frac32 x =\frac\pi 2 -\frac32 x+2k\pi \;\lor\; \frac32 x =\pi-\left(\frac\pi 2 -\frac32 x\right)+2k\pi$$

$$x =\frac\pi 6 +\frac 23k\pi \;\lor\; 0 =\frac\pi 2 +2k\pi$$

that is $x =\frac\pi 6 +\frac 23k\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your answer to $\sin({\alpha})=\cos({\alpha})$:

$${\alpha} = \pi n + {(-1)^n}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - {\alpha}\right)$$

Distribute the multiplication by $(-1)^n$:

$${\alpha} = \pi n + {(-1)^n}\frac{\pi}{2} - (-1)^n{\alpha}$$

Collect the $\alpha$ terms on the left:

$${\alpha} + (-1)^n{\alpha} = \pi n + {(-1)^n}\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Now $n$ is either even or odd. Suppose $n$ is odd, that is, $n = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.
Then $(-1)^n=-1$ and therefore
$${\alpha} - {\alpha} \stackrel?= \pi(2k + 1) - \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$0 \stackrel?= 2k\pi + \pi - \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$0 \stackrel?= 2k + \frac{1}{2}$$
which is impossible since $k$ must be an integer.

Now suppose $n$ is even, that is, $n = 2m$ for some integer $m$.
Then $(-1)^n=1$ and therefore

$${\alpha} + {\alpha} = \pi (2m) + \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$2{\alpha} = 2m\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$${\alpha} = m\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Plug in $\alpha = \dfrac{3x}{2}$, and you have
$$\frac{3x}{2} = m\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$x = \frac{2m\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6}$$
for $m \in \mathbb Z$, which is exactly the same result the book found in the end.

In short, either way to convert the trig functions
($\sin$ to $\cos$ or $\cos$ to $\sin$) is an acceptable and correct approach.
The two methods only **seem** to give different answers if you look at some of the intermediate steps and do not look at the whole solution.
The actual **answer** is the same no matter which of these two methods you use.

---

A further comment: this is what we mean when we say that
$\cos(\alpha) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - {\alpha}\right)$ is an identity
and that "the general solution for $sin({\alpha}) = sin({\beta})$ is
${\alpha} = \pi n + {(-1)^n}({\beta})$."
Your substitution for $\cos(\alpha)$ and your use of the solution for $sin({\alpha}) = sin({\beta})$ **must** give the correct answer to this problem when all other steps are followed correctly,
otherwise the identity would not be an identity or the solution would not be a solution (or perhaps both).
You cannot get wrong answers by applying only correct facts.
You get wrong answers when you apply wrong "facts".